# How do I extract one parameter from multiple request parameters using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

If I want to get out one parameter from request parameters below, how do I do so?

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***", "users_unsubscribe_mail_magazine_form"=>{"email"=>"tea@tea.com", "dm"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Send Mail", "controller"=>"users/unsubscribe_mail_magazines", "action"=>"create"}
```

I want to get "users_unsubscribe_mail_magazine_form"=>{"dm"=>"1"}, and pass the parameter to another page.
When I type into the live shell

```
params[:users_unsubscribe_mail_magazine_form][:dm]
```

I get an error message

> "!! #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for #UnsubscribeMailMagazineMailer:0x00007f14c86c5848>"

Thank you.

PS:
I am using form_for "f.submit" to send the parameters.

PPS:
This is how I call my mailer.

```
    def create
      @unsubscribe_form = Users::UnsubscribeMailMagazineForm.new mail_magazine_unsubscribe_params
      @dm = @unsubscribe_form.dm
      if @unsubscribe_form.valid?
        user = User.find_by(email: @unsubscribe_form.email)
        UnsubscribeMailMagazineMailer.unsubscribe(user).deliver_now unless user.nil?
        redirect_to action: :create_complete
      else
        render action: :new
      end
    end
```

Comment: The `params` are only available in the controller. When you want to use the parameters or single values from them in a mailer then you have to pass that value to the mailer in the arguments. How do you call your mailer?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick advice! I did not know that the params are only available in the controller... I call my mailer in my controller's create action.
I added the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` are only available in the controller. When you want to use the parameters or single values from them in a mailer then you have to pass that value to the mailer in the arguments.

Something like this should work:

```
# in the controller
UnsubscribeMailMagazineMailer.unsubscribe(
  user, params[:users_unsubscribe_mail_magazine_form][:dm]
).deliver_now if user

# in your mailer
def unsubscribe(user, dm)
  # have the `user` and the `dm` value available in local variables
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answer! That was exactly what I needed!! Thank you!!